# Date display as DATE HH:MI:SS in postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, formatting

I have a date_timestamp column in the database that stores UTC time.
Example:

```
2022-01-09 15:38:47.487-05
2022-01-08 21:28:30.989492-05
```

But in reports, I want to show only DATE and HH:MI:SS.
I would like to show it as DATE and not Character string.

eg:

```
2022-01-09 15:38:47
2022-01-08 21:28:30
```

Doing a character conversion, like
`select to_char(timestampcreated,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') cc`
shows the data the way I want but it's in CHARACTER not a date.

Any data type conversion on the "character" data is messed up. Either I can get date, or time but not both.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If this is for _display_ purposes in a report, then why does it matter that it's a character value, not a "real" timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want just a `date`:

```
select '2022-01-09 15:38:47.487-05'::timestamptz::date; 

2022-01-09

select pg_typeof('2022-01-09 15:38:47.487-05'::timestamptz::date); 

date
```

Though what you show as desired result is a timestamp, so:

```
select date_trunc('second', '2022-01-09 15:38:47.487-05'::timestamp);

2022-01-09 15:38:47

select pg_typeof(date_trunc('second', '2022-01-09 15:38:47.487-05'::timestamp));
         
timestamp without time zone
```

Though as @a_horse_with_no_name says I'm not sure why it matters for a report output whether it is a character or date/time type.

For more information on `date_trunc` see [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

Comment: horse_with_no_name  @Adrian thanks to both. Reason why I need it as date and not character is, because, the user can filter the data by a date range (including hour/min/seconds).   Your suggestion greatly helped.

Comment: Again it really does not matter: `select '2022-01-09 16:35'::timestamp = '2022-01-09 16:35'; t`

Comment: Just curious, I have to confess I have not tested it yet. But if my reports are executed in dfferent date formats (DD-MON-YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY etc.) how is it that having the data as string going to help with sorting it chronologically?

Comment: Yes, sorting of timestamp strings will not work correctly.  If the sorting is done in the query over a field that is a timestamp type then you will be okay as Postgres does not store timestamps in a format.